# How can I get a list of Symfony2 form validation errors with reference to invalid fields?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

As Symfony2 Form component with tight integration with the validation component is extremely powerful, I have hard times understanding how I can get the list of validation errors at PHP side with proper reference to the invalid field. By "reference", I mean some hint that I can further get the field and it's ID (like with `$form->get($failedChild)->vars['id']` or something).

`$form->getErrors()` returns the list of the errors, but this [array of FormErrors](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html#method_getErrors) does not include any reference to the field that is invalid.

[I found a Gist](https://gist.github.com/umpirsky/2011671) that shows something like that, but at least on 2.3 or 2.4 all errors are still bound to the main form.

`error_bubbling` option does not change the behavior as I first thought it would.

---

**Update #1**

In the end, I'd like to receive a JSON representation of all form errors and return it back to the client. A sample JSON would be something like

```
{
    "invalid_field_id": "This field has invalid value"
}
```

The ID of the field can be received over `$field->vars['id']` but it seems that all validation errors are returned in `$form->getErrors()` instead of `$field->getErrors()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$form->getErrorsAsString()` to get a *human-readable* representation of your errors. These errors are mapped to fields, unless the error can not be attached to a field, or error_bubbling is set to true.

Comment: Thanks. This is not exactly what I am looking for, I added update to the question to further clarify what are my intentions. ;)